# Apache Axis2 Web service : Gzip resquet and response

Tags: java, service, web, apache-axis

I am developed a web service that return simple string using axis2 . But i want to apply gzip compression techniques , in my web service. can anyboby give me server code and client code for it. I developed web service from this reference 
http://blog.sencide.com/2011/06/create-web-service-using-apache-axis2.html
Please provide proper guidance.

Thanx

Comment: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2008/11/enable-gzip-compression-in-tomcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do the Zip yourself, or just trying to compress the bits as they travel through the wire?

If you just want to compress the responses from your server, I know Apache has several ways of doing it.  I would suggest looking [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) as a start.

If you are trying to create your own zip file, which you are sending in the response of your WS, and the client is expecting a zip file, then you want to look at [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-frame.html).  It provides several classes that read/write various ZIP formats.  I would look at [GZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html).  It appears to work like any other OutputStream, allowing you to write out some byte[] array.

Comment: Thanx for response,Actually according apache axis2 , it support gzip compression and i know how to send req through client for gzip but what is service code for it can u give me little example